# sql query including month columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if I could get some ideas or direction on a sql query that would output column months. Here is my current query..

```
select A.assetid, A.Acquisition_Cost, B.modepreciaterate from FA00100 A
inner join FA00200 B on A.assetindex = B.assetindex
where MoDepreciateRate != '0'
```

I would like to add more columns that look as such:

```
select assetid, acquisition_cost, perdeprrate, Dec_2012, Jan_2013, Feb_2013....

where Dec_2012 = (acquisition_cost - MoDepreciateRate*(# of months))
and Jan_2013 = (acquisition_cost - MoDepreciateRate*(# of months))
```

where # of months can be changed.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Here is an example of what I would like the output to be with '# of months' = 4

```
assetid SHRTNAME    Acquisition_Cost    perdeprrate Dec_2012    Jan_2013    Feb_2013    Mar_2013
CS-013  GEH INTEG   17490.14            485.83      17004.31    16518.48    16032.65    15546.82
CS-014  WEB BRD     14560               404.4507    14155.5493  13751.0986  13346.6479  12942.1972
```

Comment: It would help us to have some sample data, along with expected results.

Comment: You may want to look into SQL Server's Pivot Table: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/.  ps. Is this query related to a JD Edwards database?

Comment: Can you clarify which database platform this is? Given that there are always only 12 (ormaybe 13 periods) in a year, and it is difficult to define a dynamic column, I suggest you do not try and do this dynamically. Also, where do you get the number of months? Is an offset from the purchase date? You'll need to at least add the purchase daet to your query to continue.

Comment: No, this is related to a Great Plains database with Fixed Assets 3rd party added. I'm wondering if I could query the backend to get a customized report out...the purchase date is the acquisition_cost. The # of months would I guess be a parameter I would setup to be used as a stored procedure but can be hardcoded as a integer...if I am making sense. Thank you.

Comment: No worries - hopefully my new answer matches what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
--setup
create table #fa00100 (assetId int, assetindex int, acquisitionCost int, dateAcquired date)
create table #fa00200 (assetIndex int, moDepreciateRate int, fullyDeprFlag nchar(1), fullyDeprFlagBit bit)

insert #fa00100 
      select 1, 1, 100, '2012-01-09'
union select 2, 2, 500, '2012-05-09'
insert #fa00200
      select 1, 10, 'N', 0
union select 2, 15, 'Y', 1
```

.

```
--solution
create table #dates (d date not null primary key clustered)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
, @pivotCols nvarchar(max)
, @thisMonth date
, @noMonths int = 4

set @thisMonth = cast(1 + GETUTCDATE() - DAY(getutcdate()) as date)
select @thisMonth
while @noMonths > 0
begin
    insert #dates select DATEADD(month,@noMonths,@thisMonth) 
    set @noMonths = @noMonths - 1
end

select @sql = ISNULL(@sql + NCHAR(10) + ',', '') 
--+ ' A.acquisitionCost - (B.moDepreciateRate * DATEDIFF(month,dateAcquired,''' + convert(nvarchar(8), d, 112) + ''')) ' --Original Line
    + ' case when A.acquisitionCost - (B.moDepreciateRate * DATEDIFF(month,dateAcquired,''' + convert(nvarchar(8), d, 112) + ''')) <= 0 then 0 else A.acquisitionCost - (B.moDepreciateRate * DATEDIFF(month,dateAcquired,''' + convert(nvarchar(8), d, 112) + ''')) end ' --new version

+ quotename(DATENAME(month, d) + '_' + right(cast(10000 + YEAR(d) as nvarchar(5)),4))
from #dates

set @sql = 'select A.assetid
, A.acquisitionCost
, B.moDepreciateRate 
,' + @sql + '
from #fa00100 A
inner join #fa00200 B 
    on A.assetindex = B.assetindex
where B.fullyDeprFlag = ''N''
and B.fullyDeprFlagBit = 0
'
--nb: B.fullyDeprFlag = ''N'' has double quotes to avoid the quotes from terminating the string
--I've also included fullyDeprFlagBit to show how the SQL would look if you had a bit column - that will perform much better and will save space over using a character column

print @sql
exec(@sql)

drop table #dates
```

.

```
    --remove temp tables from setup
drop table #fa00100
drop table #fa00200
```

Comment: I'm confused...is this a stored procedure I'm supposed to create and try using?

Comment: The above code is just T-SQL - you can run it all as it's written above.  I've used temporary tables for fa00100 and fa00200 as I don't have those on my system.  To use on your system with your existing tables remove the #s from the front of the table names (for those 2 tables only) and remove the associated drop table statements also.  If you want to wrap the code in a stored procedure, you can.

Comment: Ohhh gotcha, I had to change the "dateAcquired" to the correct column. I am receiving results now but some records are not depreciating and is going across with the same value. Thank you.

Comment: That is my fault. It involves filtering before the T-SQL is executed or modifying to include filtering. Thank you so much JohnLBevan! I will have to take your coding step by step and understand it. There are a few things I have not seen or used, which are 'quotename', 'right', and 'primary key clustered' that I will have to google. Without any formal training, this is how I am learning...I have ordered a T-SQL book. Hope it covers most of this. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries.  Quotename just puts [brackets] around a value, making it acceptable to use as a column name (it can also be used for other string escaping options too), Right is just like Excel's worksheet function - it takes a substring of N characters from the right of the given string.  Primary key clustered isn't really required in the above - it's just good practice to always have a clustered primary key on a table, so force of habit on my part. If you're new to T-SQL the following are good reference sites: http://blog.sqlauthority.com http://www.sqlservercentral.com http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: I've tried getting this 'where B.fullydeprflag = 'N' filter added right after "from #fa00100 A
inner join #fa00200 B 
    on A.assetindex = B.assetindex" but am receiving either a 'invalid column name' or "incorrect syntax near ''". Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please can you amend the question to include the create statement for your tables - without knowing what columns you have in each I can't advise - my assumption given the error would simply be that `fa00200` didn't contain the column `fullydeprflag`

Comment: Hello John, I'm not sure what you mean by including the create statement for my tables. I have not created any tables...I am just trying to extra data from an already existing database while adding depreciation information.   Fa00100 has columns assetindex, assetid, acquisition_cost;    Fa00200 has columns modepreciaterate, assetindex, fullydeprflag

Comment: "B.fullyDeprFlag = ''N'' has double quotes to avoid the quotes from terminating the string" That was it....I was using single quotes which caused the problem. Thank you very much for your help John. It is much appreciated!

Comment: John, one last problem. I don't know how to address the negative amounts. I was playing with the statement to include an 'if depreciated value is <= 0, value remains at 0' but do not know how to...would you be able to help with that as well? =)

Comment: No worries, see the line commented `--new version` above

Comment: Ohhh okay. Case when this <= 0 then that end. You are awesome John! Hope you have a great weekend and thanks again!